# Getting width of a Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I need to get the width of a custom view I'm creating by extending LinearLayout. My initial stab was to do

```
int width = this.getLayoutParams().width
```

However, this would only return -1.

Next, I attempted overriding `onMeasure(int, int)`

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);
    this.width = MeasureSpec.getSize(width);
}
```

This worked to get the width but it was being executed after I actually needed the width (I guess the view wasn't built yet?)

I specifically need it for Google Maps with this method:`` `map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, MAP_PADDING)); ``

Any suggestions on getting the width?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly set your view's width/height to static value (like x-dp or match_parent), you cannot know the size of your view until onMeasure loop is completed. Also android can call onMeasure multiple times to find suitable size, so it's not the best place to find exact size. You may have to find a way to delay your map.moveCamera to onLayout function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
// Name the activity's root view - your custom linear layout 
View view = findViewById(R.id.customLinearLayout)
int width = view.getRootView().getWidth(); // this returns the actual width of the view
```

This has always worked for me

Comment: I declare `View view` in the activity/fragment where I call the custom view, correct?

Comment: I did `this.getRootView().getWidth()` in the custom view but it yielded 0